# Test Rest API involving DB calls using Mockito

Tags: java, rest, mockito

I need to do some unit testing for my application's APIs which are REST based.

Now for example if the API is as below

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/todo/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<ToDo> getToDoById(@PathVariable("id") long id) throws ToDoException{
    //Makes DB call
    ToDo toDo = toDoService.getToDoById(id);
 }
```

The above API does a DB call to get the ID from the database.

Now when I do

```
 mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/todo/3")
 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

It is going to hit database.

Now this way mocking is becoming more of Integeration testing hitting the endpoint. Is this the right way to do or else

1. what is the right way of using Mockito for unit testing with hitting external entities like DB or webservice
2. How to mock the database and how do I get the DB data if mocked.

Comment: when testing your controller, you need to mock all service calls.

Comment: thats cool answer.. but I have seen an example where `@Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;` is used without any mocking of service calls, but results are available

Comment: they may be loading the full app context, and using it all. They may be loading mocked beans, or test beans.

Comment: @pvpkiran: if there any following helper.get Method calls after service calls they should also be mocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @pvpkiran mentioned, if you test one unit, you mock the references of this unit. So answering your questions in this case:

> what is the right way of using Mockito for unit testing with hitting external entities like DB or webservice?

Define a mock object as a class attribute in your unit test:

```
ToDoService toDoService = Mockito.mock(ToDoService.class)
```

Then tell Mockito how to react on a specific call (either in the setup method or in your test method):

```
ToDo toDo = new ToDo(...);
//configure your todo object to satisfy your needs
Mockito.when(toDoService.getToDoById(123l)).thenReturn(toDo); //returns the created object only if called with 123l
```

or

```
Mockito.when(toDoService.getToDoById(Matchers.anyLong())).thenReturn(toDo); //returns the created object for a call with any long value
```

> How to mock the database and how do I get the DB data if mocked?

In this case, you mock the whole service. If you want to test a DAO, Spring (which you obviously use) provides an embedded database you can configure with sql scripts. See the 
[documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support).

Comment: cool got it. May I know if any status code 2000 available, my application API is returning the same. Is it valid one or is it to be 200

Comment: Assuming you mean the http status code, I think it's defined to be 3 digits long. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success]. Usually, Spring mvc returns 200 by default if everything works fine.